# XSS, CSRF, Clickjacking, Rate limit vulnerability fix in Dspace ver 6.0

Tags: csrf, xss, rate-limiting, dspace, clickjacking

Pl advise how to fix the following vulnerabilities in  D Space Version  6.0

1. Stored XSS -   Cross-site scripting (also known as XSS) is a web security vulnerability which occurs when a malicious script is injected directly into a vulnerable web application cause of input validation.
2. Reflected XSS -- Reflected XSS is one of the part of Cross-Site-Scripting attacks and termed as “Non-Persistence XSS” or “Type II”.
   3  Rate Limiting-    number of wrong login attempts  to be limited to 3 & then 15 mins wait
3. CSRF-  cross site request  forgery-
4. Click jacking -
   Thanks
   Rajiv

Comment: Without sharing any code, it's impossible to provide help

Comment: This lists up generic attack vectors against any web app. What is the connection to DSpace? Please be more specific. You also can contact security@dapace.org if you found new issues that weren’t fix in the lastet release 6.4 recently.